# SSIS ODBC expressions error

Tags: ssis, odbc, informix

I'm trying to add expressions to an existing connection (ODBC -  Informix) on my connection manager inside SSIS.

My connection works fine. I use connection string, user and password, and it connects without hesitation. At least until I add expressions, expressions that are being fed by user variables (default values) such as `@[User::Connstring],@[User::User],@[User::Password]`. When I add these expressions my solution doesn't work and the Data Workflow where the ODBC was prompts `ODBC Error -1 (without work offline option selected)`. Whenever I select work offline, another error prompts "connection manager won´t acquire connection because workoffline option is set to true". Delay Validation didn't work also.

If I try to run the package, it prompts `"Error at Data Work Flow [SSIS.PipeLine]:Error on Source ODBC Validation , Error Code 0x80004005"`.